# How can I improve this template to accept lambdas in VS2012

Tags: c++, templates, boost, visual-studio-2012

The following is cute little template that I use often. Simply tells me if the given element is a member of a collection (which itself must be compatible with the find_if template):

```
// returns true if a given collection contains the given element
// NOTE: This is NOT optimized for associative containers!
template <typename ELEMENT, typename COLLECTION, typename PREDICATE>
bool contains(const COLLECTION & collection, ELEMENT element, PREDICATE predicate)
{
    return collection.end() != std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), boost::bind(predicate, element, _1));
}
```

I'm finding that VC2012 balks if I try to use a lambda as the predicate:

```
if (!contains(specs, str, [] (CString pathname, CString pattern) { return AsBool(PathMatchSpec(pathname, pattern)); }))
    continue;
```

VS2012SP1 spits out the following for the above context:

```
1>c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\15.0\3rd party\boost\boost\bind\bind.hpp(69): error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 'CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>'
1>          c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\15.0\cimex application\cimcad\macro directory.cpp(166) : see declaration of 'CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>'
1>          c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\15.0\3rd party\boost\boost\bind\bind_template.hpp(15) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::result_traits<R,F>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>              F=CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\15.0\mfc toolbox\miscellaneous.h(360) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              R=boost::_bi::unspecified,
1>              F=CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>,
1>              L=boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<CString>,boost::arg<1>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\15.0\cimex application\cimcad\macro directory.cpp(166) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool contains<CString,substring_container_adapter,CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>>(const COLLECTION &,ELEMENT,PREDICATE)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              COLLECTION=substring_container_adapter,
1>              ELEMENT=CString,
1>              PREDICATE=CMacroInterpreter::GetDirectoryOf::<lambda_60eac39ee69a5bdc77e08d06d79ae4c4>
1>          ]
```

I'm unclear on how to coerce things to accept the predicate lambda.  Seems that boost is unable to deduce the return type of the lambda.  And I'm unclear on what I can do to fix that?

I could define a local std::binary_function derivative functor.  Just seems like it would be better to fix contains<> to allow it to handle lambdas directly.

Comment: I thought we have all agreed that _all uppercase_ names where reserved for _macros_...

Comment: Erm... so <T> is not a valid template identifier?  lol

Comment: ...you just blow my mind, sir. That said, we have seen templated code break out in the real world because some dummy physics library decided to declare macros like `T`...

Comment: What boost header are you using?

Comment: @K-ballo Yeah, I agree with you in principle - the all caps names are dangerous and ugly.  This is one of my earlier templates, and I was still trying to find a style I liked.

Comment: @David It seems I'm using 1.51.  I thought I was using 1.52.  I'll have to try upgraded to see if that makes a difference.  boost::result_of is specifically mentioned, so perhaps it will now work as originally written.  However, there's little to recommend not using std::bind now that the std library is as good as boost in this respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with `boost::bind`. Using `std::bind` instead, your code builds fine with lambdas in VS2012:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename ELEMENT, typename COLLECTION, typename PREDICATE>
bool contains(const COLLECTION & collection, ELEMENT element, PREDICATE predicate)
{
    return collection.end() != std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(), std::bind(predicate, element, std::placeholders::_1));
}

std::vector<int> a;

int main()
{
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(42);
    bool c = contains(a, 42, [](int a, int b) { return a == b; });
    return 0;
}
```

The same code builds just fine with `g++` as well.

Comment: The code I posted doesn't require boost. `std::bind`, which is essentially the same as `boost::bind`, is in the C++11 standard. It can be used by including the `functional` header.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try using another lambda:

```
template <typename ELEMENT, typename COLLECTION, typename PREDICATE>
bool contains(const COLLECTION & collection, ELEMENT element, PREDICATE predicate)
{
    typedef typename COLLECTION::value_type VALUE;

    return collection.end() != std::find_if(collection.begin(), collection.end(),
      [&]( VALUE const & e ){ return predicate( element, e ); });
}
```

Comment: @David `_1` represents the first argument to the call on function operator of the object produced by `bind`.  In the case of `std::find_if` this is the element from the container being evaluated.  So `bind( predicate, element, _1 )` produces a unary function object which is equivalent to calling `predicate( element, _1 )`.  The lambda expression in my answer does the same thing, no library required.

Comment: David - the _1 isn't being used here because the second lambda is being handed what is effectively _1 (here called argument e).  And the the bind is gone, because the extra lambda does the binding by copy by referencing 'element'.

Comment: Huh - now I'm thinking this might be the better solution... :P

Comment: However, this solution explicitly specifies that the members of COLLECTION are convertible to ELEMENT (and forces the conversion).  It would be better if they were handed to predicate natively, without conversion.

Comment: @Mordachai You're right, I assumed you wanted to compare apples to apples.  See edit for new "fruit salad" version.